# Shortcode just with a php code

Tags: php, shortcode

I have one php file in wordpress where have a php variable `$tt->name`.

This `$tt->name` I want to convert into a shortcode so I canuse it somewhere else on the website.

Let me explain step by step.
First I have search where user choose taxonomy and then type in search box and click on search.

On search result page, taxonomy is as `$tt->name` (Because there are 3-4 types of result, depend on what user choose, like if 1st taxonomy then another result and if 2nd taxonomy then a message, if 3rd taxonomy then a pic and so on..

But all on the top have line, *"You have chosen taxonomy 1"* and that 1 is `$tt->name` in code actually. Now there is a form just in next with title, contact us and there is a field which I want value of `$tt->name`. That's why I need shortcode. Because I want to use this shortcode somewhere else in the website.

Any solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: What is `$tt->name` and where does it come from? Can you describe what the purpose of the shortcode is in non-technical terms? There's not a lot of context here to understand what's going on

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. It's actually on search result page. This is taxonomy. Like all countries, and which country user choose, it show at the place of $tt->name. But on same page, there is form also and form use shortcode. So to put in that form, I need shortcode for this...

Comment: Is this a shortcode ran using `do_shortcode`? Or do you have a custom search page template?

Comment: No no, it's not shortcode at all.. It's just a custom search page template.

Comment: I meant for the form, there's no code in your question so it's very difficult to figure out what's going on and how to change it, are you aware that you can modify the normal search functionality via `search.php` for the template and `pre_get_posts` to modify what gets searched?

Comment: Ok, let me explain step by step. First I have search where user choose taxonomy and then type in search box and click on search. On search result page, taxonomy is as $tt->name (Because there are 3-4 types of result, depend on what user choose, like if 1st taxonomy then another result and if 2nd taxonomy then a message, if 3rd taxonomy then a pic and so on.. But all on the top have line, "You have chosen taxonomy 1 and that 1 is $tt->name in code actually. Now there is a form just in next with title, contact us and there is a field which I want value of $tt->name. That's why I need shortcode

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code for the page? It's 1000x easier to just see what you're doing than have to parse a description, additionally, other people who come here will end up having to read the comments and do all the comprehension work all over again, edit your question so it's clearer, you can do that via the `edit` link under the tags

Comment: hmmm now that you mention you need this value on other pages on the website too, that complicates things. I see there is no code in your question, please update your question with the code for your search page. I think this description is incomplete, and a less technical description would be better. e.g. "the user gets shown 3 types of house in a form then that type of house gets shown at the top of every page", too much focus on the technical side of things, not clear what you're actually trying to do, makes it super difficult to imagine it in your head. What does this page/form actually do?

Comment: Without the code, I'm struggling to picture how it works, e.g. is the bottom of the template just showing the contents of the page, and that's where the contact form is? WP doesn't come with a contact form out of the box, how is the contact form implemented? This question is extremely difficult to answer without the code for that template

Comment: Sounds like you want to pass the taxonomy name along with other contact form details.  In which case a shortcode is not going to cut it.    You either need to change contact form to include the variable in it's fields, or if the contact form accepts values passed in url for it's fields then you can pass it the tt-name as a value for it's field name.

Comment: Hello anmari... The form I am using, it can accept shortcode in value=""

Comment: Question: Will this value `$tt->name` be available on other pages? Or, do you need to save the searched taxonomy first before navigating away?

Answer (score 0):

It sound like you can accomplish this with 2 PHP functions.

1) Save the searched taxonomy to the user's session. When they re-run the search function, update the taxonomy that was searched. This way if its saved to their session, you can use it elsewhere on the site just for that user.

2) Create a shortcode to display that saved taxonomy.

```
// ... search function that gets $tt. 
save_searched_taxonomy($tt->name);
//...

function save_searched_taxonomy($taxonomy){
    $_SESSION['searched_taxonomy'] == $taxonomy;
}


function get_searched_taxonomy_shortcode(){
    return $_SESSION['saved_taxonomy'];
}
add_shortcode('searched_taxonomy', 'get_searched_taxonomy_shortcode');
```

Then on other pages, you can call your shortcode and have it refer to whatever that user searched for.

```
[searched_taxonomy]
```

Comment: Hello italiansoda. Thanks a lot for your help. But this one didn't work for me ;(

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Also here is more about session. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp Maybe you need to do `session_start();` at the top of your code somewhere.